# Use variable value in a Math expression in Shell Scripting

Tags: bash

I am trying to use the value of the iteration counter in a FOR loop in another mathematical expression inside the loop. Example code:

```
#! /bin/bash

for i in {100..1}
do
    j=$($i-1)
    echo $i $j
done
```

However, this does not work. I want to get the output as shown below:

```
100 99
99 98
```

and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in {100..1}
do
    j=$(($i-1))  <- Here is the change.
    echo $i $j
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to double parenthesis :

```
j=$(( $i-1 ))
```

or :

```
j=$(( i-1 ))
```

This syntax works :

```
$[ $i-1 ]
```

**But you shoud avoid it.** 
It's deprecated and will be removed in upcoming versions of Bash.

Moreover, you can decrement with :

```
j=i
echo $i $(( --j ))
```

For more about calculation in Bash :

https://www.shell-tips.com/2010/06/14/performing-math-calculation-in-bash/

Comment: or just not use j at all as it is redundant and is always 1 less than `i`, just print `i-1`

Comment: You're right, It doesn't make a lot of sense, it's just to cover all syntax.